# what is wrong with function getInput?

Tags: c, pointers, codeblocks

Unfinished the program, i dont know why, values are not stored in weight, drag and time variables(inside structure USER_INPUT), if i printf weight, drag and time, they are 0.
I havent started writing rest of the program, did i make some mistakes in main function?

```
#include  <stdio.h>

#define G 9.8
#define index 3

typedef struct
{
double weight;
double drag;
double time;
}USER_INPUT;

double velocities[index];

double getInput(USER_INPUT);
double calculateVelocities(USER_INPUT);

void main(void)
{
double velocity;
USER_INPUT input;

getInput(input);
calculateVelocities(input);



printf("Velocities for the parachuties with weight %f\n", input.weight);
printf("and a drag coefficient %f\n", input.drag);

printf("\n\n    Time     Velocities m/s\n");
printf("---------------------------------\n");
printf("        %f       %f\n", input.time, velocities[0]);
printf("        %f       %f\n", input.time, velocities[1]);
printf("        %f       %f\n", input.time, velocities[2]);




}

double getInput(USER_INPUT input)
{
printf("Please enter weight, drag and time:\n");
scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &input.weight, &input.drag, &input.time);

printf("%f  %f  %f\n"), input.weight, input.drag, input.time;
}

double calculateVelocities(USER_INPUT input)
{
velocities[0]=1;
velocities[1]=2;
velocities[2]=3;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different issues with this.

1. This is a typo under `getInput`:

   ```
   printf("%f  %f  %f\n"), input.weight, input.drag, input.time;
   ```

   it should be this:

   ```
   printf("%f  %f  %f\n", input.weight, input.drag, input.time);
   ```
2. Your functions `getInput` and `getVelocities` should return `void` instead of `double`.
   Change this:

   ```
   double getInput(USER_INPUT);
   double calculateVelocities(USER_INPUT);
   ```

   to this

   ```
   void getInput(USER_INPUT);
   void calculateVelocities(USER_INPUT);
   ```

   And then do the same things for the definitions.
3. You're passing `USER_INPUT` to your functions by *value* instead of as pointers. If you want to set the fields of that `struct`, then pass it as a pointer and then dereference it once in the function. Passing by value means that the function receiving the object actually just copies the object contents to a new one. So referencing `&input.width` is referencing the `width` field on the copy object, not the original back in your `main` function.

   For example, your `getInput` function should be:

   ```
   // declaration
   void getInput(USER_INPUT*);

   // stuff

   // definition
   void getInput(USER_INPUT *input)
   {
     printf("Please enter weight, drag and time:\n");
     scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &((*input).weight), &((*input).drag), &((*input).time));

     printf("%f  %f  %f\n", input->weight, input->drag, input->time);
   }
   ```

   The excessive parenthesis are to be utterly clear about what is going on. But you can more simply write `&((*input).weight)` as `&(input->weight)`.

   And then you'll have to do the same sort of thing with your `calculateVelocities` function.

   Finally, to call those newly defined functions, do like the following:

   ```
   getInput(&input);
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @user133174 No problem!

Comment: I really can't recommend `&((*input).weight)` compared with `&input->weight`; the former is obfuscation, not clarification.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'll update my answer. I was just trying to be clear about what was going on because I don't think he learned much about pointers yet.